# indexes of values that do not match between 2 vectors

Tags: r

I have a vector `v1 = c(0,1,0,1,1)` and a vector `v2 = c(1,1,0,1,0)`. How do I return the indexes where the values between the two vectors DO NOT match?

ex:

```
v1 = c(0,1,0,1,1)
v2 = c(1,1,0,1,0)
```

expected output

```
out_vector = c(1, 5)
```

Indexes 1 and 5 do not match between vectors `v1` and `v2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can compare 2 vectors element wise with `==` and then use `which` to get their index position where they do not match.

```
which(!v1 == v2)
#[1] 1 5
```

or more straight forward as @thelatemail suggested

```
which(v1 != v2)
#[1] 1 5
```

Comment: Why not `which(v1 != v2)` ?

Comment: I'll take it! Good answer!

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different method than what @Ronak used, we could also view the operation as a bitwise XOR between the two vectors:

```
v1 = c(0,1,0,1,1)
v2 = c(1,1,0,1,0)

which(xor(v1, v2))
[1] 1 5
```